# Chartjs - Bar Chart - Backgroud Gradient

Tags: angularjs, canvas, chart.js, bar-chart, gradient

i have a angularjs project with chartjs .
I want to have a bar-chart with gradient background.
Searching in google i have found this code

```
var backgroundGradient = $element.find('canvas')[0].getContext('2d').createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 600);

backgroundGradient.addColorStop(0.0, "#fcffa4")
backgroundGradient.addColorStop(0.3, "#f98e08")
backgroundGradient.addColorStop(0.7, "#bb3754")
backgroundGradient.addColorStop(01, "#570f6d")

BarChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = backgroundGradient;
```

but if I resize the chart the background change, not remain the same gradient, until it becomes single color.

Can you help me?

Comment: no one who can help me???